# With python dataframes add column of counts of rows that meet condition to each row that meets it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Say I have a python DataFrame with the following structure:

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,3,5,6],[1,4,6,7],[1,4,6,7],[1,4,6,7]])
Out[262]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  1  2  3  4
2  1  3  5  6
3  1  4  6  7
4  1  4  6  7
5  1  4  6  7
```

How can I add a column called 'ct' that counts the instances of the DataFrame where column 1-3 match to **each row that matches**... so the DataFrame would look like this when all is completed.

```
   0  1  2  3  ct
0  1  2  3  4  2
1  1  2  3  4  2
2  1  3  5  6  1
3  1  4  6  7  3
4  1  4  6  7  3
5  1  4  6  7  3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['ct'] = df.groupby([1,2,3])[1].transform('size')
#alternatively
#df['ct'] = df.groupby([1,2,3])[1].transform(len)
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  ct
0  1  2  3  4   2
1  1  2  3  4   2
2  1  3  5  6   1
3  1  4  6  7   3
4  1  4  6  7   3
5  1  4  6  7   3
```

Comment: You sir, are a life saver.

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day!

Comment: If that worked, don't forget to accept @jezrael's answer!

Comment: @SavageHenry - Thank you.